# How to call function only when fragment is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have 5 fragments that call function from the activity in their onResume method. The problem is as follows: they call the function multiple times, but I want them to call it only one time. I am using the Navigation(NavHostFragment) and NavController to control the fragments. So my question is - Is there a way to call said function only when fragment is attached and visible?
I searched for a way to do it but without success so any help and advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "they call the function multiple times"? As in they call the function every time you close and reopen the app?

Here is an overview of the [fragment life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating) and some more [information on handling that life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle). If you only want the fragments to call the function once, maybe you could add the function to an earlier stage, such as onAttach() or onCreate().

Comment: I am trying to create step view with different imageViews as background of each step. The views transitions between 3 colours with animations. My problem is that the function that changes the colour is called 3 times. From the links about the [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle) I tried to put the calls in **onAttach()**. The problem persist. Tried to debug without much success. I am a young with minimal experience in programming, so I cant pinpoint exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score -2):

thanks for sharing your code btw, pretty sure we're all python programs that can analyze your code with our minds

Comment: Leave a comment if you want to ask for additional information like a code snippet. Sarcastic answers aren't helpful and pollute the answer feed.